# Dirac Delta in polar coordinates, integrating delta from 0 to $\infty$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Many sources mention how to recast Dirac's Delta function from Cartesian into polar or spherical coordinates. They say e.g. for polar:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\vec{x})\,{\rm d}^3x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\delta(y)\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1r\delta(r)\delta(\phi)\,r\,{\rm d}\phi\,{\rm d}r$$

(while they mostly work with $\delta(x-x')\delta(y-y')$ I recast it to the special case of $x'=0=y'$).

however, if I rewrite the last integral as:
$$\int_0^\infty\delta(r)\,{\rm d}r\int_0^{2\pi}\delta(\phi)\,{\rm d}\phi$$

what are these integrals? They should both evaluate to $1$ to keep $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\vec{x})\,{\rm d}^3x=1$ as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398777/dirac-delta-in-polar-coordinates) but that is far from obvious to me (I do not see how they came to the result in the answer's last equation). [Another similar topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951874/delta-function-at-the-origin-in-polar-coordinates) does not really resolve the issue to my understanding. Actually, it occured to me:

$$\int_0^\infty\delta(r)\,{\rm d}r=\int_0^\infty\frac{{\rm d} H(x)}{{\rm d}x}\,{\rm d}x=H(\infty)-H(0) = 1 - H(0)$$

where $H(x)$ is the standard Heavyside function: $H(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $H(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually not welldefined as they stand, but a common way to solve it is to identify the integrals as being taken from just below $0$, e.g.
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\int_{-\epsilon}^\infty \delta(r) \, \mathrm{d}r$$